# If/Else - If String Not Displaying?

Tags: javascript

I have a prompt to enter a string("A Name"). On the `if` part of my `if/else` statement. When the execution goes through and a string is entered, it does what it's supposed to do.

However in the actual statement `if(x === null)` nothing occurs when the `cancel` button is clicked. I think it is because of what is under the "y" variable.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    var x = prompt('Enter a name');
    var y = x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase();

    if(x === null){
        document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Welcome to My Site!";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site";
    }
```

Comment: I think x is still a string with zero length if nothing is entered, not null.

Comment: @logic-unit It is null if you click cancel or x-close the input

Comment: @LGSon It's null if they click cancel, empty string if they click ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this

```js
var x = prompt('Enter a name');
var y = (x) ? x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';

alert(x === null ? "Welcome to My Site!" : "Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site");
```

If you also want it to handle an empty string, like if someone only push OK and not enter any characters, change `x === true` to `!x`

```js
var x = prompt('Enter a name');
var y = (x) ? x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';

alert(!x ? "Welcome to My Site!" : "Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site");
```

Comment: may as well do `alert(y.length < 1 ? "Welcome to My Site!" : Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site");` while you're at it

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trimming after uppercasing the first character.

Comment: Yes i dont want to alert though i want it to write to a DIV sect. but. why did you put if y.length is less then 1 i dont understand that can you explain to me in detail. I would greatly appreciate it.. because .length i though just returns a number of how much like eg., 32.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, will update :) ... and trim all input if one enter space only

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do that before the truthy check?

Comment: @djechlin if x is null I get error, so i trim the full string only if x is not null

Comment: @BrandonLanglois Updated my answer to explain. Is it ok now?

Comment: "I'm not sure why you're trimming after uppercasing the first character."

Because I want the first Character the be upperCase and the rest to be lowerCase.

Comment: @BrandonLanglois I am triming the full input in case someone enters space characters

Comment: Then you have to write code to handle the null case?

Comment: @djechlin It does if you press cancel

Comment: My mistake...  code can solve the appearance of 2 cases though.

Comment: @LGson - I dont really like the complication with the .length I just dont see a reason for it... i mean if they input nothing i can add that after no problem but if they click cancel in the prompt window then it will = NULL and thats what im looking for..i appreciate every bit of help though

Comment: @BrandonLanglois I took all out but the null check for reading the result. Is it ok now?

Comment: @BrandonLanglois As of now, if someone just click ok without write anything it will pass as if someone wrote a name, is that how you want?

Comment: @LGson Man thats EXACTLY what I want.. FAST> SIMPLE > FUNCTIONAL

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when `x` has the value `null`, as you expect it for the cancel button case, the statement

> ```
> var y = x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase();
> ```

will throw an exception - you can't call those methods on `null`. The exception breaks your script and prevents it from displaying anything. Check your [error console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525).

You'll have to move it inside your else block, to execute it only when `x` is a string:

```
var x = prompt('Enter a name');
if (x === null) {
    document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Welcome to My Site!";
} else {
    var y = x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you enter nothing `prompt` will return an empty string `''`, if you click cancel button `x` will be equal to `null`, so in both cases you'll get [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value which you can handle using `if(x)` instead of `if(x === null)`.

Also manipulate `x` value inside `if(x)` block.

Comment: If cancelled is pressed it returns null

Comment: @LGSon, thanks for comment, I've used it in update answer.

Answer (score -1):

`x` is null when a users presses 'Cancel'

`x` is an empty string when user presses 'OK'

The problem is that you can't set `y` when `x` is `null`

```js
 var x = prompt('Enter a name');
 if(x===null || x==='' )
 {
     document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Welcome to My Site!";
 }
 else
 {
     var y = x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase();
     document.getElementById("name_placement").innerHTML = "Hello " + y + ", Welcome To My Site";
 }
```

```html
<div id="name_placement"></div>
```

Comment: This will fail (JS error) if the user presses cancel.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks. I fixed it.